# XSS Protection in a Sinatra App

Tags: ruby, sinatra, xss

For `html = '<b><a href="http://foo.com/">foo</a></b><img src="http://foo.com/bar.jpg" />'` and similar input, including javascript, will something like this (`Sanitize.clean(@post.content) # => 'foo'`) cover all bases to prevent users from injecting javascript and html into the database?

Should I take additional steps to sanitize user input?

Comment: Why would you prevent user entering HTML and JS to the DB? I would rather prevent displaying such content raw. Something like http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#escaping_html

Comment: Thanks for the response. How would this be done in HTML without HAML? And I have an overall concern about this approach. If I prevent the html & js from displaying raw, what would be the purpose of allowing it to save to the DB in the first place? I would prefer not allowing the data to save to avoid rendering ugly html/js tags in my UI.

Comment: HTML is merely one possible presentation, which should be separated from your content. If the user wanted to enter character `>`, I don't think you should transform it anyhow before saving to the database. Instead, you should rely on your framework (or templating library, anyway), to prepare the content before rendering it to HTML. So, what do you write your Sinatra views in?

Comment: I am using ERB for templating

Comment: This should do the trick then: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB/Util.html#method-c-h

Comment: Thanks, I think I will use ERB to filter it as you suggest

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ERB::Util method `html_escape` (aliased as the shorter `h`)

See: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB/Util.html#method-c-h

*Note: Copied from Mladen's comment as a community wiki answer*